# What would an optimal robot look like intended to replace military infantry?

Tags: robots, military

In science fiction and real life, robot designs vary quite extensively, and rightly so as each design is meant to tackle a different task. A more common design is based on the human form: four limbed, bipedal, head on top etc.

But what would be the best design for an all purpose robot designed to replace military infantry?  Humans are able to accomplish a wide array of tasks and yet I feel a robot designed to look human is quite limited. Should it even have limbs? How many? Should it have legs? Wheels? Both? How big should it be? Is human size too big? Too small?

I would like it to be a single structure, so no nanobots that can form bigger bots. Consider the budget to be incredibly vast, so don't worry too much about what it costs.

Comment: There is no objective "optimal" unless at know what tasks will it have to perform. Without this defined everyone will answer with his ideas of robot job in mind. And of course idea of universal robot is not economical. If I need an astro droid, I won't pay for it to be able to cook or perform veterinarian surgery. Why anyone would?

Comment: Ah, good point on your comparison, I'll try to edit the question to be less general.

Comment: And sorry for poor language in previous comment. I was in a hurry and can't edit it now.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Robotic Replacement for Infantry](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/56767/809) now?

Comment: Yes... Yes it is... I didn't see that question.

Comment: Not sure how to delete it from my phone. People are welcome to close as duplicate until I'm able to get to a computer

Comment: No need to delete it. Duplicates are good, allows to find questions with different wording etc. Or you may try to make your question better than the other one (as it's closed as too broad at the moment) and then this one will stay open :) **You can't delete because it's upvoted and have upvoted answer** - no one wants decent content to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, a bit too late to really dig deep and fix the question, I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: Don't worry if it'll get put on hold. Improve anyway. We can always reopen it.

Comment: What came first to my mind: "a boot stamping on a human face — forever." (George Orwell, *1984* )

Comment: What are infantry bad at, what they do very well? They're squidgy and vulnerable, they get scared. They're very very good at hiding behind, under, and in things. They can wield weaponry that can kill much harder platforms. They can be very creative improvisers. In a close urban environment everything about the terrain is designed explicitly for their form factor. Unlike the rural scenario where all sorts of other shapes may work as well or better. Taking all that into account, the perfect infantry robot would obviously be a dual wielding chrome skeleton. Science fact.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it would not be one frame. Just as you don't have only one model of tank, and one model of ships, you would have a array of different robots optimized for a specific role/terrain.

Exemples:

- Need to deal with civilians, and you don't want to make them afraid? You don't need a lot of firepower, but have something they can relate to, so a humanoid form.
- Need to rush buildings and just make them go boom? A cat like or toy car suicide bomber like [Goliath tracked mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliath_tracked_mine).
- Secure a area already under control (road barrage)? Some sort of mini tanks with appropriate weaponry should be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

For a military combat robot, I'd prefer a dog or cat style design.

4 legs for speed and manoeuvrability and a low centre of mass. Main weapon on the side, left and right, to cover the complete 360° area around and above the robot.

Main sensors in the head, containing IR and optical sensors, ears are supersonic radar, similar to bats. A tail as an electronic whip for close combat and a smoke grenade launcher in the butt, to cover emergency evasive manoeuvers.

The military transport would be similar, just bigger, horse sized, and without weapons, but a big storage in the armoured belly, big enough to hold a grown human in embryo position.

I would not recommend bipeds, because the high up centre of mass and the unstable position when only one leg is on the ground.

Comment: Personally,  I'd hazard a guess that with good inertial sensors, a single leg working much like a pogo-stick could be a good design.

Comment: No, you could easily throw it over, as soon as the centre of mass is outside the body radius. When you push it, it cannot counteract like it would do with 2 or more legs.
Although a pogo stick robot would be a great distraction for enemy forces :o)

Comment: So, the problem is not about sensing the g-force, but to counteract.

Comment: With a pogo stick you are airborne most of the time and can redirect the stick to absorb/recycle  the impact energy and determine the trajectory of the next bounce. Freed from the limitations of human anatomy I think a pogo-stock robot could "always" land stick down, using tricks similar to those a cat uses to "always" land feet-down.

Comment: @nigel222 A cat only "always" lands feet down when the fall is far enough to give it time to recover from any situation, there are certainly times when this is not the case.

Comment: Agreed - hence the quotes. One of a robot's strengths is that it can do something simple, inhumanly fast. Like get its stick pointed downwards again! And yes, there would need to be a slower fallback manouver, for when it does land wrong.

Comment: @JamesTrotter a significant portion of cats not being able to right themselves from 5 stories is also due to not realizing they're falling for precious (fractional) seconds. A cat deliberately jumping (like our pogobot) will always get it right.

Answer (score 3):

There is NOT an *optimal* shape, ESPECIALLY for military use.

That's not the way military things are designed: think about *general purpose* airplanes, boats and submarines. Those projects are often too full of compromises and they're sub-optimal in every scenario. For each intended use (or, at best, for a family of uses) you need a specific design.

Few things to consider (but there are many more):

- Bipeds and quadrupeds aren't the best for equilibrium (tripods are far better because for three points there is always one plane). *Best* is a vague concept, they may be *flexible* and provide a great maneuverability paying the cost of increased amount of energy (and complexity) used to keep balance. However quadrupeds may be better to carry heavier stuff. Consider that:

  - **Mass distribution** (just for example think about crossing an iced lake) is important; more *legs* and better you distribute weight.
  - Quadrupeds are more stable than bipeds and, distributing mass, you may need smaller, less expensive, infrastructure.
- Simpler design is **easier to produce** in case of war and it's cheaper (again it's very important for volume production in constrained resources scenarios).
- World is **designed for bipeds** (human beings) and if your *soldiers* need to interact with such environment then two *legs* are better (also with a comparable size).
- We already have a huge amount of **existing weapons**, to redesign them to fit those robots isn't viable (at least at very beginning). It's much better if they can *handle* what already exists.
- Sometimes wheels, skates, etc are better than *legs*. Again it's about intended use. Do you easily walk above snow? What's the maximum speed for a reliable device with high complex moving mechanical parts (like legs)? For military components **reliability** is the master.
- If your soldiers will need to **interact with human beings** (for example for pace keeping missions) then an humanoid shape (but not too much humanoid) is more appreciated, regardless their effectiveness in combat.
- According to **combat environment** you will need completely different shielding and it may then impose completely different choices.
- **Different missions** impose different *soldiers*. Infiltration? Smaller and fast (probably with less shielding). Frontal impact? High shielding and speed is less critical. Quick response? Faster and with huge impact, probably leaving thick shield out...
- **Technical limitations** will impose their own rules. Do you want a fast, highly armored tripod which can combat for one week inside enemies' country? You probably don't have the battery to power such soldiers...

Comment: _Bipeds and quadrupeds aren't the best for equilibrium_ Not quite - bipeds are inherently unstable (but can be balanced, and this can provide mobility/maneuverablitly - think of Eurofighter; designed to be unstable (so much so that it is beyond human capability to control) so that it maneuvers well).  Quadruped (or any platform with four points of contact) may not be stable (they do tend to rock on a uneven surface) but they require _more_ displacement to fall over than three legs. This is why stools and tables often have 3 legs, but the majority of cars etc are based around a square chassis.

Comment: @Baldrickk I agree with you, the true point should be the amount of energy used to keep equilibrium. Updated to reflect this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but I'm convinced it will not look any like a human. An ideal military robot is bacteria-like. Very small, very deadly and present in very big numbers. It probably also should be able to propel itself, so it could move much faster than usual bacteria.

In practice it may be very hard to design something so small, that can move very fast. So in the end, it may be much bigger but still will remain similar. Imagine a small balls, almost not noticeable, but that can move very fast and kill in seconds. Maybe something like an AI-powered bullet or rocket?

If we assume we are not so much technically advanced, it will still be small, just bigger. The drones, that carry a firearm is a good example. Other option is something like a small spider that can jump very far and fast. I do not remember the movie name, but there was one (probably more than one) that showed one of such things.

All of this if we assume a real warfare - combat. If we are peacekeeping, surely something humanoid will work better, but I guess this is closer to police task, rather than military.

Comment: RE Spider robots: Are you perhaps thinking of the Retinal Scanners in Minority Report?

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix It looks very similar to what I remember, so this film is probably what I was talking about. Unfortunately, I just remember a single frame from it, so unless I review it completely (which I probably should do), I cannot confirm - but it looks very alike.

Answer (score 1):

## Humanoid

I'm anthropomorphising of course, but a humanoid shape is pretty optimal (since we evolved over millions of years into our currently optimal shape and size).

This becomes more efficient when robots collaborate on tasks as well.

Comment: Well, it's pretty optimal for tasks we've designed for our shape.

Comment: There's nothing "optimal" about us; it's just that certain other apes with a slightly different phenotype died more often in a particular environment than ones like us. But look at how often human women die from childbirth compared to other apes (in the absence of advanced medicine), or the design of our shoulder joints, or wisdom teeth. And think of the organisms that have remained essentially unchanged for hundreds of millions of years....

Comment: @MaliceVidrine - Robots don't reproduce in the same way that we do, and difficulty in birth is a compromise for our design and not a design fault as such.  Yes, there's organisms and animals that have remained unchanged, but for a combination of mobility and tool use, I can't think of any better form than the higher primates.

Comment: The specific examples were just to point out the messiness of our evolution, not specific problems robots would have. Considering we don't have to design robots after any previous base species, we can do so much better than anthropomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

While @Pete is right, he failed to provide a reason, which i would like to provide.

There are many good generalist shapes. To be precise, every living thing on our planet (and elsewhere, should there be any) has a really good generlalist shape.

But there is only one shape that can benefit fully from the environment shaped by humans, and that is the humanoid form, precisely for that reason:
Everything around us is optimized for our form. Shelves and cupboards are where a humanoid can reach them easily. Any machinery you find is built for humans to operate.
And this is especially though in warfare: Every weapon is designed so a human can easily distinguish the right end from the wrong end, and use the trigger, reloading mechanisms and whatnot. 
So, if you want a generalist combat robot, give it a humanoid form, so he can ride in tanks and aircraft, use weapons that the opposing side spontaneously decided they won't need any more, and reach any places that humans can.

Feel free to add fancy extras, but make sure that the general features are kept humanoid.

Answer (score 1):

In order for our bots to be as efficient as possible and be usable in as many different environments as possible, we're probably not going to see any humanoid bots. The sole exception to that would be if we needed some sort of psychological edge, in which case, mounting our bots in child-mannequin bodies would be ideal.

Nightmare fuel not withstanding, first of all we need to look at mobility. The ideal combatant is one who can be deployed in a short time, in any terrain and through a wide variety of means. So we'll want them to be reasonably small and light. This helps both with transport and because they're small, they'll be harder to hit. In terms of surface area versus volume, we're going to want them to be as close to a sphere as possible, giving us a maximal volume to hide important components while providing a minimal surface that we need to slap armor on. Unfortunately, spheres are annoying to deal with and tend to roll around a lot so we'll probably see something closer to a dodecagon (which co-incidentally, also looks an awful lot like the angular shapes we see on radar-confusing vehicles)

Allright, so we're looking at bots that are probably somewhere between a football and a beachball in size. I think that in terms of weaponry and mobility, we should be following the example of the A-10 Warthog. That is: half of our bot is firepower, the other half is dedicated to getting it someplace where it can deploy said firepower. I'm thinking a number of small ion thrusters, set in different locations in the chassis.
As for weaponry, since we're dealing with warbots in the future, we're probably building them either with high-end coil or rail rifles, with the whole of the bot built off a miniature reactor or big-ass battery.
Speaking of weaponry, some of our bots are probably going to be intended for short-term engagements and should be equipped with a battery of dumb-fire rockets for harder targets.

Answer (score 1):

Here at Real Soldier Corporation we've designed the optimal hybrid robo-warrior.

As Real People™, we are [pretty efficient](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46788/7456) at converting fuel to energy, and able to harvest energy from a wide source of foodstuffs. But most importantly, we're really efficient at moving through a variety of terrain. We can climb over, under, and through things. Our infrastructure is also fairly well designed around something us-sized.

We've designed the fighting force of the future. Our newest product, Meat Soldier™ overcomes many of the design problems that Real People™ soldiers have faced over the years.

- **Frailty**. The most tragic design flaw in Real People™ is that a small projectile through the heart or head stop operation. We have engineered Meat Soldier™ with redundant fluid pumps in various locations throughout its body, with smaller emergency pumps in each of the limbs. Meat Soldier™ is capable of continued, though limited, operation even in the unlikely event that every Meat Heart™ is compromised. We have also [carefully designed the circulatory system](http://askanaturalist.com/why-don%E2%80%99t-ducks%E2%80%99-feet-freeze/) to increase the range of temperatures our Meat Soldier™ can operate without tissue damage
- **Sensory input**. While Real People™ are limited touch, taste, sight, smell, and sound, Meat Soldier™ can be equipped with a wide range of Sense-Stations™. They can view wavelengths in the entire spectrum, including infra-red and ultra-violet. Their auditory frequency response can be expanded to 0-10,000GHz, well outside the range of human hearing, but allows Meat Soldier™ to communicate at higher frequencies, as well as identify other signatures made by certain electronics. Sense-Stations™ are not just limited to their point of attachment. Using proprietary technology, most Sense-Stations™ can be re-attached at different points, allowing for maximum flexibility in where and how your Meat Soldier™ can see, taste, hear, and touch.
- **Speed of Communication**. About the fastest you're going to get using Real People™ communicating via English is 200-300WPM. [583-630, if you're really good](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv4nimqsajA) (but good luck trying to process that). Our Meat Soldiers are able to broadcast information [much quicker](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28749/8854). Typical communication is digitally over WiFi or Bluetooth®, but Meat Soldiers can also fall back to auditory communication. Communication is encrypted using AES-256 bit by default, and if you have the need to communicate with your Meat Soldier™ through the auditory channel we have an implantable cochlear implant that can perform real-time decryption. If necessary or desired you can also instruct your Meat Soldier™ to communicate using decrypted audio in the language of your choice, making them ideal for situations where you may require an interpreter. Other scenarios that the Meat Soldier excels - imagine that your Meat Soldier™ has found Bad Guy™'s Bad Guy Hideout™. Using the full-spectrum Sense-Station™ package, including optional Hand Eye Coordination™ Sense-Station™ package Meat Soldier™ only needs to expose its fingertips to gather the most intelligence with the least amount of exposure, confirming that Bad Guy™ is on the premises. In a Real Person™ situation, coordinates and confirmation will have to be communicated via at least a whisper, but upon confirmation, Meat Soldier™ can silently radio back its exact route and entire Meat Soldier™ Intelligence Package™. Its fellow Meat Soldiers™ will now know the *exact* route to the destination, along with all intelligence gathered along the way, such as potential ambush points, dangerous terrain, weak spots in defense, sensors, booby traps, etc. Of course, if the situation changes, Meat Soldier™ is capable of making real-time adjustments to the battle plan, but in the typical case the entire Meat Soldier™ unit can walk in the exact footsteps of those before it, so any track will look like it was only one individual.
- **Hesitation**. In battle hesitation will kill a Real Person™. Meat Soldiers™ have no hesitation. When a threat is identified, it's eliminated. Because Meat Soldier™ units can act in nearly immediate communication, if necessary, one Meat Soldier™ can identify the target while another one eliminates it. Best of all Meat Soldier™ has no regrets, no remorse, and no PTSD!
- **Infection/disease/loss of limbs**. For Real People™, disease and infection can cause pretty serious problems. But our new Meat Soldier™ Grow and Go™ accessories allow you to plug and play new limbs. Our carefully engineered process produces limbs to such a high specification that a damaged foot, arm, or leg can be replaced simply by detaching the old one and plugging in the new ones. And if a Meat Soldier™ is rendered inoperative, any viable limbs can be harvested by its compatriots.
- **Rest/Fatigue**. Granted, more stress will wear out Meat Soldier™ quicker and may void your warranty, but in an emergency situation, Meat Soldier™ has override commands that can disable self-protection routines, allowing them to push themselves far past that of Real People™, completely ignoring injury. And of course the Intelligence Package™ will be recorded and transmitted to other Meat Soldier™ units so your only loss is that of the actual parts. Meat Soldier™ has no need to sleep, so they also get 8-10 more hours of productive time per 24 hour cycle, and one Meat Soldier™ can operate heavy machinery indefinitely.
- **Variance**. With your typical Real People™ they can be tall, short, fat, skinny. Some have more endurance, others have less. Each Meat Soldier™ model is engineered with such high quality and attention to detail that they are almost impossible to tell apart by default. Of course we offer patented SkinTint™ technology and MeatToo™ tattooing to meet your branding needs. We offer three primary Meat Soldier models. Meat Soldier™ Classic has an average build, at 6'0" and weighing in at 180lbs unloaded, and capable of carrying 90lbs fully loaded. Tunnel Rat Meat Soldier™ has a slim build, coming in at 4' and weighing 65lbs, capable of 25lbs fully loaded. The Tank Meat Soldier™ model comes in at 6'5" and 325lbs, capable of carrying a 200lb load. Typically you'll want to match parts with the same model, but in an emergency situation you can interchange limbs between any line of Meat Soldier™ as they have been designed to work with every permutation of limb attachments. Having such consistency in our models allows you to tightly optimize your base layout and armor configurations for your Meat Soldier™.
- **Learning**. While Real People™ take quite a while to master a new skill, Meat Soldier™ sKill Transfer™ is almost immediate. And unit-to-unit transfers require no training time, so if one unit is lost or damaged, its experiences remain. If a skill is unnecessary, or the experience is atypical, it is also possible to remove sets of training data from your Meat Soldier™.

These are some of the many benefits to having your very own force of Meat Soldiers™. As the Real People™ behind Real Soldier Corporation, we look forward to your business.

Answer (score 0):

## It's simple:

[image: The soldier of the future]

The best soldier is that which you can't fight. Soldier of the future would either use the best camo available(which, in some distant future, might mean high % of invisibility), or simply won't be a single soldier(swarm of nanobots, some disease, or any other modern invention).